# Rigid Body properties

Tags: python, rigidbody

I'm new in using blender and bpy python module. I have a set of 20 cubes and I might to give them a rigid body properties, I saw to doing it, it need select the cube one by one. Is there a way to give rigid body properties to all cubes at the same time with coding with bpy module?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add rigid body properties to all the cubes in one go, but you can copy the rigid body from one cube to all the other ones. First, give one of the cubes a rigid body and then select all the other cubes. (Make sure that the cube, which has the rigid body, is active, so highlighted in orange.) You can then copy the rigid body from that one cube by going to "Object > Rigid Body > Copy from Active".

[image]

If you decide later on that you want to make a change to the properties, you can make it effect all the cubes simultaneously by selecting them all, and holding down "alt" while you change one of the properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback. I've got another question on this one, is that possible to do it with python code? If yes is someone able to do it or give me any suggestion to do it!?

Comment: Just enter the following two lines of code: ```bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_add()``` adds rigid body properties to one of the cubes and ```bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_settings_copy()``` copies the rigid body from that one cube to the others.